OKTA Authentication Flow non-ui-based scenarios with same User context
Scenario-1:
A user is accessing the service-1 through UI. This access to service-1 is authenticated through the Login page. Now while calling the REST API of service-1, service-1 needs to call service-2 for some data. What should be the OKTA authentication flow between service-1 and service-2 here. One requirement is that service-2 needs to know about the current user, as it has RLS (Row-level-security) implemented. How the same user information will flow from service-1 to service-2?
Scenario-2: The REST APIs of service-2 need to be called through some automation scripts written in Python. What OKTA Authentication-flow needs to be implemented by Python application. This Python application does not have any front-end, so Login-page scenario will not work here. Since the service-2 is RLS based, the user context is must while connecting.
There are so many Authentication-flow in OKTA, I need to know what can be used in these scenarios. The service-2 as single set of APIs, it does not have different APIs based on consumers (service-1 and Python app).

Scenario 1
You need to design how to share access tokens across APIs and solutions depend on how much service 1 trusts service 2:

You could forward the original access token so that you deliver the user identity and other claims in a verifiable way.

Or service 1 can use token exchange to reduce the token privileges before sending it to service 2.


All APIs should enforce the correct authorization, like checking for their required scopes.
Scenario 2
The solution depends on the privileges that the operator of the automation scripts should have:

If the operator is a backend process that can update data for all users, you can use the client credentials flow and the access token will not have a user identity.

Otherwise an automation script can trigger a code flow that invokes the system browser to sign in an interactive user and get an access token with a user identity.


Access Token Design
In all cases, I would recommend that you start with your access token design so that APIs receive access tokens with scopes and claims that restrict client privileges to APIs and enable the correct authorization.
